# ObjectProperty has no attribute (Kivy, Python 3.x)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

This questions has been asked and answered quite often, but I still can't get it to work. I want to access a widget that is a children of another widget. For this I used an ObjectProperty. When I try to access the ObjectProperty (by opening any file via the FileChooser popup) to change the label's text I get this error:

> self.pdfpages.text = "change to this" AttributeError:
>   'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'text'

Do I need to initialize the ObjectProperty? Or is there a problem with my .kv structure?

main.py

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0') # replace with your current kivy version !
# Kivy Imports
from kivy.app import App
#UI Eleemnts
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.scatter import Scatter
from kivy.uix.image import Image

#Core Elements
from kivy.core.image import Image as CoreImage
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

# Python Imports
import os

class Window(BoxLayout):
    #add child widgets (in kv file)
    pass


class PDFView(ScrollView):
    pdfpages = ObjectProperty()

    def newPage(self, filepath):
         #here the error occurs   
         self.pdfpages.text = "change to this"

class SideBar(BoxLayout):
    def openfile(self):
        print("Button pressed")
        OpenDialog().open()

class OpenDialog(Popup):
    def cancelfile(self):
        #close popup
        self.dismiss()
        print("No file opened")

    def openfile(self, path, selection):
        #selection can contain multiple files, [0] is first or only
        self.dismiss()
        print("Opened File: " + os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
        #open PDFView class
        PDFView.newPage(PDFView, os.path.join(path, selection[0]))        


class PDFEditor(App):
    title = "PDFEditor"
    #gets called on startup
    #load program
    def build(self):
        #return root node
        return Window()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    PDFEditor().run()
```

PDFEditor.kv

```
<Window>:
    #this is the main (root) "window"
    orientation: "horizontal"
    SideBar:
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
    PDFView:
        size_hint: (.9, 1)

<PDFView>:
    #handler for ObjectProperty
    pdfpages: pdfpages
    Scatter:
    #only zoom
        BoxLayout:
            #add Images in here somehow
            orientation: "vertical"
            Label:
                id: pdfpages
                text: "hi"


<SideBar>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    Button:
        id: btn_openfile
        on_release: root.openfile()
        text: "Open File"
    Label:
        text: "Hello!"

<OpenDialog>:
    title: "Choose File"
    BoxLayout:
        #Fullscreen
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        orientation: "vertical"
        FileChooserListView:
            id: chsr_open
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint_y: None
            height: 30
            Button:
                text: "Cancel"
                on_release: root.cancelfile()
            Button:
                text: "Open"
                on_release: root.openfile(chsr_open.path, chsr_open.selection)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you set the text of a new instance, wich is not even on the window, rather than the one you allready have.
To fix this, you need to access the one you have.

First, make your `Window` as an `App` attribute, so you can reference it later.

```
class PDFEditor(App):
    title = "PDFEditor"
    def build(self):
        self.root = Window()
        return self.root
```

Then give the `PDFView` an `id` in kv

```
<Window>:
    orientation: "horizontal"
    SideBar:
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
    PDFView:
        id: pdfview
        size_hint: (.9, 1)
```

Then in your `openfile` method, you can get the running apps `root` attribute you created earlier, like this.

```
def openfile(self, path, selection):
    self.dismiss()
    print("Opened File: " + os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
    app = App.get_running_app()
    pdf = app.root.ids.pdfview
    pdf.newPage(os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
```

That way you can access the `ids` of your `Window` class

Comment: This way I can access members from other classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change your `openfile` method to this:

```
def openfile(self, path, selection):
    #selection can contain multiple files, [0] is first or only
    self.dismiss()
    print("Opened File: " + os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
    #open PDFView class
    PDFView().newPage(PDFView, os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
```

`PDFView` is the class, `PDFView()` is an instance of this class, what you need

**edit**

the label does not change because you are creating a new one without replacing it. So if I understand well all you want is to replace the text of your PDFView. There is many ways to do that but I don't want to edit much your code: try this:

```
...
class OpenDialog(Popup):
    ...
    def openfile(self, path, selection):
        #selection can contain multiple files, [0] is first or only
        self.dismiss()
        print("Opened File: " + os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
        #open PDFView class
        app.window.ids.pdfview.newPage(PDFView, os.path.join(path, selection[0]))
    ...
...

class PDFEditor(App):
    ...
    def build(self):
        #return root node
        self.window = Window()
        return self.window

app = PDFEditor()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

in your kv:

```
...
<Window>:
    #this is the main (root) "window"
    orientation: "horizontal"
    SideBar:
        size_hint: (.1, 1)
    PDFView:
        id: pdfview
        size_hint: (.9, 1)
...
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't throw an error, but the text won't get changed.

Comment: I see that your answer is pretty similar to the one @EL3PHANTEN gave. Which is good as they both work :) Just wondering: when would one choose self.window compared to self.root in the build method?

Comment: @Spreng0r root or window is just a name you choose.. I just saw it as the root of the app. Might as well be window or spam_n_eggs